# unable to display textbox in form through jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a display of some data through jquery. now I want to put some textbox in front of data but it doesn't show the 'n' numbers of textbox only single box display. see my code

```
$("#jobcard").html(data[i]['jobcard_id']);
var qty = data[i]['jobcard_material_qty'].split(","); 
for(var j =0; j<qty.length; j++){ //qty.length =5         
$("#issue").html('<input type="text" name="qty_issue_"'+j+ '><br>');
          }
```

i alert(qty.length) //got ans 5
so i just need input 5 input boxes but i got sinlge box only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the JQuery method [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) for this!

```js
var qty = {
  length: 5
};
var data = [{
  jobcard_id: 1
}];
var i=0;
$("#jobcard").html(data[i]['jobcard_id']);
for (var j = 0; j < qty.length; j++) { //qty.length =5         
  $("#issue").append('<input type="text" name="qty_issue_"' + j + '><br>');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="jobcard"></div>
<div id="issue"></div>
```